# warning: Ambiguous Content: The app icon set "AppIcon" has an unassigned child (editor->xcode 10.0)

Tags: ios, swift, ionic-framework, ionic3, xcode10

When I click on the icon is shows the given message "AppIcon unassigned child " I do not understand why the error message give and how can solve it .

[image]

Comment: You should remove this icon. Looks like the JSON in the AppIcon.asset has an entry for this icon. Hope you are not missing any icon.

Comment: here is my json - {
      "size" : "1024x1024",
      "idiom" : "watch-marketing",
      "filename" : "icon-1024.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "44x44",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "filename" : "AppIcon44x44@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "role" : "longLook",
      "subtype" : "42mm"
    }

Comment: Just delete the icon-1026.png. It should never exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum sized icon we need for AppIcon asset is of size 1024x1024. Icon which shows warning is not needed and so it is showing warning.

To remove this warning:
Right click on icon and select **Remove Selected Items**.

[image]